How to merge 3D face model with sunglass in blender through Scripting?
I have a 3D model file of a face in USDZ format, and I created a sunglass frame and temple separately. How can I merge them together with correct positioning through a backend script?
Also, how can I provide manual measurements through backend code, such as resizing the bridge and temple?
This is the code I came up with.
import bpy


bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath="/Users/nisha/Downloads/model1.blend",
    directory="/Users/nisha/Downloads/model1.blend/Object/",
    filename="modelface" 
)

# Step 1: Import sunglasses front frame and temple
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath="/Users/nisha/Downloads/aviator1.blend",
    directory="/Users/nisha/Downloads/aviator1.blend/Object/",
    filename="frame" 
)
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath="/Users/nisha/Downloads/T2.blend",
    directory="/Users/nisha/Downloads/T2.blend/Object/",
    filename="temple"  # Make sure this is the correct object name in the file
)

# Step 2: Merge the frame and temple into one object
bpy.data.objects['frame'].select_set(True)
bpy.data.objects['temple'].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.join()
merged_sunglasses = bpy.context.object  # The merged sunglasses object

# Step 3: Resize the sunglasses based on interpupillary distance
interpupillary = 60.0
current_width = merged_sunglasses.dimensions.x  # Current width of the sunglasses

# Rescale sunglasses based on interpupillary distance
scale_factor = interpupillary / current_width
merged_sunglasses.scale = (scale_factor, scale_factor, scale_factor)

# Apply the scale
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)

# Step 4: Position the sunglasses on the face model
face_model = bpy.data.objects["modelface"]  # Use the exact name of the face model object

# Use face measurements
root_of_nose = 9.089051  # Example measurement for nose position

# Position the sunglasses relative to the face model
merged_sunglasses.location = (
    face_model.location.x,  # Center on face
    face_model.location.y + root_of_nose,  # Adjust based on nose measurement
    face_model.location.z  # Adjust height
)

# Step 5: Save the final scene
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="/Users/nisha/Downloads/resized_sunglasses_on_face.blend")



